# How far I can detect faces using inbuilt facial detection present in 4K camera devices?

Tags: android, face-detection

I wanted to detect the faces from more than 30 feet using the inbuilt device camera.

It seems that I can able to detect the face in between the range of 1 to 10 feet. But after that, I could not able to detect the faces. Is there any way to increase the limit of facial detection for long distance(for example 30 feet and more)?

Thanks!

Comment: How does your question relate to programming?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Yes

Comment: You can't answer `Yes` to `How` question.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Sorry I miss understood your question, It is related to programming as well as a hardware. I hope I cleared you.

Comment: **How** is it related to programming???